# 'TypeError: Invalid MIME type' when manually submitting form data to action method

Tags: reactjs

I want to manually pass a piece of data to an action with useSubmit. What I have so far is to push it in form data as follows:

```
const frmData=new FormData()
frmData.append('pathname',window.location.pathname)
submit(frmData,{action:'/logout', method:'post'})
```

Action:

```
export const action=(ctx)=>async({request, params})=>{
  let formData=Object.fromEntries(await request.formData()) <-- I think this is generating the error
  ...................
  return null
}
```

It is reaching the action method but what is happening is sometimes it's working and sometimes it's generating error: TypeError: Invalid MIME type. Any suggestions?

Comment: What library are you using for submitting? Why did you do `.fromEntries(await ...)`?

Comment: @technophyle I used useSubmit hook. I used Async await because it's how I learnt to do it when submitting a Form